# How do I match all % except one that is followed by s?

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the regex for matching all percent-like characters except one that is followed by `s`?

I want to escape all `%` with `%%` but I do not want `%s` to become `%%s`. I am using Ruby to replace all occurrences of `%` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following gsub should do the trick if you are using a string as your input

```
a = a.gsub(/%(?!s)/, '%%')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `%(?!s)` and replace that with `%%`.

The `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead. Adapt `s` in the construct if ever you have other characters than `s` to "unmatch".

And see @JosephRuby's answer which actually gives the ruby code ;)

Comment: +1.  Although if I understand the OP, it should simply be `%(?!s)`.